# how to solve data loading issue in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

All:

I wonder how can I make Chrome handle about 4GB data loaded into it? My use case is:

The Front End starts and tries to download 3GB json file data and makes some calculation. But Chrome always crash.

Any solution for this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you work with large data typically optimization rule is :

**Don't read all data at once, don't save all data at once**.

If your code allows perform calculations "step-by-step", split your JSON to small parts (for example, by 50Mb). 
Of course, it works slowly, however this approach allows to keep memory.

This optimization rule is useful not only for JS and browser, but for various languages and platforms.

Comment: thanks. Another thing I am confused is: say If the dowloaded data is not large, but the calculation in the frontend will generate large data( like 1GB data stored in an Array), will that lead Chrome crash, or only the downloading of large data will make it crash?

Comment: @Kuan I think both cases will crash the browser. It should be rewritten.